# Array of array double won't adding a new element in kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have array of array double but it won't add element after using `.plusElement`or `.plus`. code below inside from view model that returns it.data which is a list of object

#### Code

```
var ageEntry : Int
val dataObject : Array<Array<Double>> = arrayOf()
 for (dataWeight in it.data!!){
     ageEntry = dataWeight.date.toLocalDate().getAgeInMonth().toString().toInt()
     dataObject.plusElement(arrayOf(ageEntry.toDouble(), dataWeight.weight.toDouble()))
     Log.d("DATA_SERIES_BARU", "setupViewInstance: ${dataObject.contentToString()}")
 }
```

#### Log

[image]

Comment: Arrays are fixed-length.  Lists are variable-length; they're also a lot more flexible, can have read-only references, play better with generics, have far better support in the standard library, have decent toString() and equals() methods, have multiple implementations, can be overridden.  Arrays are mainly for interoperability, varargs, and low-level implementation; everywhere else, lists are preferred

Comment: Adding to what @gidds said: `plus()` doesn't modify existing array, but creates a new one.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply but I finally found my way to add that array

Answer (score 1):

The OP's proposed answer is subpar to say the least. If you need a mutable data structure, use a list not an array. I suggest something like this:

```
it.data?.fold(ArrayList<Array<Double>>()) { list, dataWeight ->
    val ageEntry = dataWeight.date.toLocalDate().getAgeInMonth().toString().toInt()
    list.add(arrayOf(ageEntry.toDouble(), dataWeight.weight.toDouble()))
    list
}
```

If you absolutely need an array at the end, you can easily convert it using `toTypedArray()`.

Answer (score -2):

**Im adding this function to add array Element**

```
fun <T> appendArray(arr: Array<T>, element: T): Array<T?> {
        val array = arr.copyOf(arr.size + 1)
        array[arr.size] = element
        return array
    }
```

**then you can call it**

```
appendArray(copyDataObject, arrayOf(ageEntry,arrayOf(arrayOf(2.0, 3.0)))
```

Comment: Scary code tbh. Please use a list instead of an array. Arrays are fixed length and while it's possible to change their size, lists are meant to be used in cases where elements need to be added or deleted. If you need an array at the end of your operations, you can easily convert the list to an array.